# R: summation of rows in a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

What I want to do: I have a data frame where the first column consists of strings, and the rest of the columns are filled with numeric values. I want to add the first three rows to the rest of the rows in groups of three while applying different factors to the rows, like: row1*x + row4*y, row1*x + row5*y, row1*x + row6*y, then row2*x+row4*y, and so on until row3*x+row6*y. Then I want to do the same thing again, but with different values for x and y, and then a third time with different values for x and y. Then I want to do the same with rows 1-3 and 7-9, then the same with 1-3 and 10-12. The exact order is important. I want to write all of this as rows in a new data frame.

I also want to combine the respective strings of the first column, add a marker so I know which summation I made, and then a continuous counter per group. I want to add this to my data frame of results, so I can see which row came from where.

What I have: After extensive juggling with for loops, this code finally does exactly what I want, but it is ugly, and it is reaaaaaally slow with my actual data (actual data frame has 1762 columns).

```
numbers <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(1:100,12,rep=TRUE))) 
id <- data.frame(id=c("d1","d2","d3","v11","v12","v13","v21","v22","v23","v31","v32","v33"))
data <- cbind(id,numbers)

results <- data.frame() 
data.raw <- data[,-1] 
legend <- data.frame()
q=1 
#################### rows 1-3 with rows 4-6
k=1 # my continuous counter
for(i in 1:3) {
    for(j in 4:6){
        results <- rbind(results,0.99*(data.raw[i,])+0.01*(data.raw[j,]))
        legend[q,1] <- paste(data[i,1],data[j,1],"01",k,sep="_")
        q=q+1
        k=k+1 }}
k=1
for(i in 1:3){
    for(j in 4:6){  
        results <- rbind(results,0.95*(data.raw[i,])+0.05*(data.raw[j,]))
        legend[q,1] <- paste(data[i,1],data[j,1],"05",k,sep="_")
    q=q+1
    k=k+1 }}
k=1
for(i in (1:3)){
    for(j in 4:6){  
        results <- rbind(results,0.9*(data.raw[i,])+0.1*(data.raw[j,]))
        legend[q,1] <- paste(data[i,1],data[j,1],"10",k,sep="_")
        q=q+1 
        k=k+1   }}
#################### rows 1-3 with rows 7-9
k=1
for(i in 1:3){
    for(j in 7:9){
        results <- rbind(results,0.99*(data.raw[i,])+0.01*(data.raw[j,]))
        legend[q,1] <- paste(data[i,1],data[j,1],"01",k,sep="_")
        q=q+1
        k=k+1 }}
k=1
for(i in 1:3){
    for(j in 7:9){  
        results <- rbind(results,0.95*(data.raw[i,])+0.05*(data.raw[j,]))
        legend[q,1] <- paste(data[i,1],data[j,1],"05",k,sep="_")
        q=q+1
        k=k+1 }}
k=1
for(i in 1:3){
    for(j in 7:9){  
        results <- rbind(results,0.9*(data.raw[i,])+0.1*(data.raw[j,]))
        legend[q,1] <- paste(data[i,1],data[j,1],"10",k,sep="_")
        q=q+1 
        k=k+1   }}
#################### rows 1-3 with rows 10-12
k=1
for(i in 1:3){
    for(j in 10:12){
        results <- rbind(results,0.99*(data.raw[i,])+0.01*(data.raw[j,]))
        legend[q,1] <- paste(data[i,1],data[j,1],"01",k,sep="_")
        q=q+1
        k=k+1 }}
k=1
for(i in 1:3){
    for(j in 10:12){    
        results <- rbind(results,0.95*(data.raw[i,])+0.05*(data.raw[j,]))
        legend[q,1] <- paste(data[i,1],data[j,1],"05",k,sep="_")
        q=q+1
        k=k+1 }}
k=1
for(i in 1:3){
    for(j in 10:12){    
        results <- rbind(results,0.9*(data.raw[i,])+0.1*(data.raw[j,]))
        legend[q,1] <- paste(data[i,1],data[j,1],"10",k,sep="_")
        q=q+1 
        k=k+1   }}

mydataframe <- cbind(legend,results)
```

What I'd like to have: something prettier, shorter, and faster. Apparently it is possible to replace for loops with functions, but here's where I'm lost. I guess I could use something from the `apply` family, but I don't completely understand the concept of functions yet, and then it all gets more complicated with the descriptive strings.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first step, instead of working with data frames, convert them to matrices.  Simply changing

```
results <- data.frame() 
data.raw <- data[,-1]
```

to

```
results<-c()
data.raw <- as.matrix(data[,-1] )
```

at the top should speed it up a lot.

Comment: Does `results<-c()` really help? i.e. you would still need to _grow_ the object which is the costly operation. Instead you could initialize it to the required size (or roughly the size if it's not clearly defined from the beginning) by using `?vector`.

Comment: It helps a little.  I get 318ms with the original code, 43ms with just changing `data.raw` and 17ms changing both.  Initializing results to the right size would probably make it faster.  I don't know if R is smart enough to figure out that `results` is being replaced with each `rbind` so it can actually do the whole thing in linear amortized time.

Comment: Thank you! That really helped, the code is super fast now! Who thought it would be so easy. :)